# Why does the Makefile expression "export INTEGER_VAR ?= $(if $(BOOL_VAR),2,5)" result in INTEGER_VAR=2 when BOOL_VAR is false?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

My Makefile has a line which reads:

```
export INTEGER_VAR ?= $(if $(BOOL_VAR),2,5)
```

Then `INTEGER_VAR` is used to make some decisions in the following lines.

When I do `make BOOL_VAR=false` the `INTEGER_VAR` takes the value of **2**

Can anyone help me figure out why?

I am using GNU Make version 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$(if` just checks for empty/non-empty.  It has no concept of types or things like `true` or `false`.  So with `BOOL_VAR=false` the tested thing `$(BOOL_VAR)` is not an empty string and so is logically true.